# HitTestObject Both MovieClip Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to make a player and 2 Circles.

When the player hit the first Circle, then the Circle will also move as like player. Continue with the second Circle, if the second circle get hit by the first circle (while the player is moving and pushing the first circle), the second circle will also move as like player's speed movement!

Can you solve the problems, please ... :)
Thank You!

Comment: Have you try any code yet?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and explain what is or isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addChild()` method.

```
var circle1Hit:Boolean = false;
var circle2Hit:Boolean = false;

function myHitTest(me:MouseEvent): void 
{
    if (player.hitTestObject(circle1) && circle1Hit == false){
        circle1Hit = true;
        var _x:Number = circle1.x - player.x;
        var _y:Number = circle1.y - player.y;
        player.addChild(circle1)
        circle1.x = _x;
        circle1.y = _y;
    }
    if (player.hitTestObject(circle2) && circle2Hit == false)
    {
        circle2Hit = true;
        var _x:Number = circle2.x - player.x;
        var _y:Number = circle2.y - player.y;
        player.addChild(circle2)
        circle2.x = _x;
        circle2.y = _y;
    }
}
```

For further reading check out this [great tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-the-display-list-basix--active-2255) that explains containers and OOP really well.  Also check out the one on Arrays from the same author [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-arrays-basix--active-1703).  By using an array, you could add even more circles to the array and all of them would be able to stick like these two do without having to have a separate bit of code for each circle like we have here.